# Char array wont print at indexes

Tags: c#, .net

I have a char array that print A-Z if i convert it to a string but when I try to get a character from an index location I get nothing? ..

```
    char[] codes= new char[156];
    for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++) codes[i] = (char)i;
    Console.WriteLine(codes[2]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're starting to store the `char`'s at index 65..

```
Console.WriteLine(codes[65]); // A
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that you created a gigantic array but only are populating a small section of it and indexing into a portion that contains no data.

You could consider simplifying using a range..

```
var chars = Enumerable.Range(65, 90).Select(c => (char)c).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(chars[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can modify your code to this.

```
char[] codes = new char[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    codes[i] = (char)i;
    codes[i] += 'A';
}

Console.WriteLine(codes[2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You try the below code
Console.WriteLine(codes[2].ToString());
The reason is Console.WriteLine can display only the string value.

Comment: this is not correct.also the issue is the op is filling the array from index 65,so codes[2] is empty.